# Inserting/Adding/Updating elements in matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

Let's say I've initialized a matrix/array that has 400 rows, 3 columns:

```
distances = np.zeros([400, 3], dtype=np.float64)
```

Now, I have a for loop that returns 1200 objects (float values) and I want to "append" each element into `distances` (row by row) or assign those float values to each element in the matrix like:

```
distances[0,1] = item1,
distances[0,2] = item2, 
distances[0,3] = item3, 
distances[1,1] = item4,
distances[1,2] = .....
```

How can I do this? I tried `numpy.append` and `numpy.insert` but I failed. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to change the size of the matrix or you want the elements of the existing 400x3 matrix to have those values assigned?

Comment: I want to assign those 1200 objects (float values) into the 400x3 matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gather you items in  a list, convert this list into NumPy array and reshape:

```
distances = np.array([item1, item2, ... item1200], dtype=float).reshape((400, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want random access, you can do it with enumeration (to get row by row access) and slice assignment:

```
distances = np.zeros([400, 3], dtype=np.float64)

start=[1,2,3]
for i,_ in enumerate(distances):
    distances[i][:]=start
    start=[x+1 for x in start]
>>> distances
[[   1.    2.    3.]
 [   2.    3.    4.]
 [   3.    4.    5.]
 ..., 
 [ 398.  399.  400.]
 [ 399.  400.  401.]
 [ 400.  401.  402.]]
```